# how much bleeding was there VS How much bleed you got?

Tags: meaning

If my girlfriend having a vaginal spotting or bleeding , and if I want to ask her how much bleeding she got, which could be better Question?

how much bleeding was there VS How much bleed you got?

Comment: Idiomatic questions would be 'how much blood was there ?' and 'how long did it bleed for ?'  'How much bleeding' mixes the two up, both mathematically and semantically.

Comment: IMO you should use v or vs for versus, not VS.

Answer (score -1):

The better way of asking a question is How much did she bleed. because How much bleed you git seems to be incorrect. As for my knowledge we ask how much did she bleed after vaginal discharge.

Comment: then how much did you bleed would be better right?